# Cloud Foundry back-end and public apps

Tags: security, microservices, cloud-foundry, 12factor

In most solutions some apps should be public and some should be internal-only accessible.

**Is there a proven configuration pattern of such a solution?**

The simple way to do this may be to create two CF spaces (in the same CF organization):

- the `internal space`

  - apps in this space are binded to the `internal domain` (e.g: *.my-internal-cf.cloud) that points the `internal load-balancer`
  - the `internal domain` is main shared domain
  - the `internal load-balancer` isn't accessible from the Internet, can be accessible only for apps from the Cloud Foundry
  - the `internal space` has access to the backing-services (cf security-groups)
- the `public space`:

  - apps in this space are binded to the `public domain` (e.g: *.my-pub-cf.cloud) that points the `public load-balancer`
  - the `public load-balancer` is accessible from the Internet and passing only traffic to the `public domains`
  - the `public space` has limited access to the backing-services or even has only access to apps from the `internal space` (cf security-groups)

**Is this configuration secure?**

**Can it be done more easily?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of orgs & spaces here is irrelevant to an app being public/private.  Orgs & spaces are for internally organizing your apps and limiting access to those through the cf cli.  You can use whatever structure makes sense for your team & company.

For making an app public/private, it all depends on the use of routes.  If you want public access to an app, you bind a public route to the app (i.e. not an internal route).  If you do not want an app to be public either bind an [internal route](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#internal-routes) or don't bind a route at all.  If you bind an internal route, you can use [the platform's DNS-based discovery](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/understand-cf-networking.html#service-discovery) or bring your own, like Eureka or Consul.  If you don't bind a route you would communicate through a service, like a message broker.

You can even control the traffic between two apps on the container-to-container network via [policies](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/understand-cf-networking.html#policies).  This allows you to allow or restrict traffic based on type & port.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel.
"The use of orgs & spaces here is irrelevant to an app being public/private" - generally yes, but in described configuration apps from internal spaces have only internal domains/routes available, so become internal-only. I know that this is not a perfect solution but is stable. "Internal route" is the feature I need but it is currently experimental. Can I use it in production? When will it become stable?

Comment: If you're not using the internal route feature, it's not really an internal route.  You could add a domain like `my-internal-cf.cloud`, restrict where it can be resolved and even restrict access to the domain in your spaces, but ultimately an app with a route on that domain will still have the route published to Gorouter. All it would take is for someone to know the internal route, `curl` & a forged `Host` header to trick Gorouter into sending a request to one of your quasi internal routes.

Comment: Using the internal route feature would be better because Gorouter would never route to an internal only domain.  The only way to use that domain is from the container to container network.  If security and isolation are a primary concern, using the internal route feature is the way to go.  Starting in PCF 2.2, internal routes are enabled by default, so it should be pretty stable.